# TextView with different colors

Tags: android, textview

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to make an app that checks if the user writes the sentence in the right way. If he doesn't, he will see the words that he wrote wrong in red, otherwise will see the whole sentence in green.

```
check_b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String[] dan_res = dan.split(" ");
        String[] text_res = check_text.getText().toString().split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i<text_res.length; i++) {
            if (text_res[i] != dan_res[i]) {
                SpannableString text = new SpannableString(text_res[i]);  
                // make "Lorem" (characters 0 to 5) red  
                text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, i, 0);
                dan_view.append(text_res[i]);
            }
            else {
                dan_view.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You say you have a problem with your code. What are you seeing and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When I see a question saying "there was a problem" without explaining what the problem is, I'll vote to close as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" or "unclear what you're asking" 9 times out of 9. "There was a problem" doesn't give anyone a starting point for examining the problem. Explain what you're trying to accomplish, what results you're getting, and how they differ from the intended results. Include any error messages you receive.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way is to use HTML:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>This is red.</font><font color='green'>And this is green.</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to apply an [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) to your EditText and change color in filter method

```
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                  if (dest ... goodstring) // set color of EditText green
                  else // set color of EditText red
            }
```